# charge old battery with adapter

Tags: battery, charging, charger

I want to use my old hp notebook battery but I dont have the laptop and now I want to charge it... but it has 5 input, I mean a port which gets in 5 blade....

only thing that is write in it is 14.8V and capacity 4400mah and model:H48 and it is compatible with Hp omnibook xe4 , xe4000,.... and lots of other series.....

I have simple 18v adaptor.... but I dont know how to put just one positive and one negative wire of adapter to 5 input it have and also what voltage it need.... thanks :)

Comment: Batteries and chargers aren't interchangeable like that.

Comment: why?batteries have one positive and one negative head.... that give and get the voltage ...... so how's there structure? and also it was  notebook battery which charge with adapter.... so how does notebook do the charging(I want this)?

Comment: A component cell has a positive and negative, and electrical characteristics based on its chemistry.  A laptop battery can be more like a device (multiple cells and circuitry).  Chargers can be more than a simple voltage supply.  The laptop includes charge control circuitry designed around the battery's chemistry.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to charge a battery using a simple voltage from something like a wall-wart style power brick is a good way to start a fire.

Many batteries require a specific voltage and current profile to charge them safely, they often need a constant and "*very particular** current charge below 90% and switch to a slightly higher constant voltage but lower current for the final part of the charge.

A wall adaptor will not do a current/votage changeover and may have very poor current limiting that either browns out the adaptor or otherwise "hiccups", neither of which are going to do your battery any good.

Even if it works well, without the correct current limiting it could well be delivering more current than is safe for the battery charge, causing it to overheat and become dangerous.

The *best* option is to use the charging circuit that was designed to work with those batteries, that means the one built into the laptops the battery was meant to work in.

---

As described by the Battery University page on [charging lithium ion batteries](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries)

[image]

In the picture above the current is shown by the dotted line while battery cell voltage is the solid line.

The battery charger is a voltage limiting device with a maximum current limit that prevents the battery from getting too hot during the initial high-current phase (the current limiting phase). As the battery is charged it's voltage picks up and once voltage passes a certain point current draw falls and it is here where it enters the voltage limited phase.

Using too high a current can cause the battery to heat up and damage itself, venting gas or flame, and having too high a voltage can also cause damage:

> Lithium-ion operates safely within the designated operating voltages; however, the battery becomes unstable if inadvertently charged to a higher than specified voltage. Prolonged charging above 4.30V on a Li-ion designed for 4.20V/cell will plate metallic lithium on the anode. The cathode material becomes an oxidizing agent, loses stability and produces carbon dioxide (CO2). The cell pressure rises and if the charge is allowed to continue, the current interrupt device (CID) responsible for cell safety disconnects at 1,000–1,380kPa (145–200psi). Should the pressure rise further, the safety membrane on some Li-ion bursts open at about 3,450kPa (500psi) and the cell might eventually vent with flame.

Lithium batteries have pretty tight tolerances on their charging voltage due to their chemistry. You *might* get away with partially charging a cell so long as your maximum voltage is close, your current limit is reasonably low and you stay away from the constant voltage phase but you'll never really want to be fully charging the battery unless you like flaming balls of noxious chemicals on your desk.

Seriously, you are better off using a dedicated charger. You *can* just connect a supply to the correct pins, but you do so at your own risk.

Comment: thank for your answer.... can you tell a little exactly that why it act like that , that need different current and voltage and the reason they charge like that.... what would happen if it charge with constant voltage and ampere .... and how could I find the exact thing for it? nothing write on it....

Comment: @nimabehrang I've added some more detail and a source where they describe a lot about the batteries. Essentially though you can initially "pour" a high current into the battery but doing so would cause it to become dangerously hot, hence we limit the current and voltage from the charger droops. Once the battery has enough charge it accepts less current and enters the second phase where we hold the voltage and just let it accept the current it wants. Because there are so many different LiPo chemistries with different limits it is safer to use the device they were designed for to charge them.

Comment: @nimabehrang, this post was surely worth upvoting!

Comment: @nimabehrang: There is variety in chemistry and design within lithium-ion, so batteries and chargers aren't guaranteed to be compatible.  Then there are NiCad and NiMH batteries with completely different characteristics.  Add to that some manufacturers build in logic to identify their OEM batteries and chargers.  Matching voltage and current capacity is just the tip of the iceberg.